# Spawn в определённой области

Tags: c#, unity3d

Приветствую, как реализовать спавнер, что бы он спавнил объекты в заданной пощаде?

```
public float Repeat;
public GameObject Enemy1;
public GameObject Terrain;
float width, lenth;
public  int spwn;
private void Start()
{
    width =Terrain.transform.localScale.x;
    lenth =Terrain.transform.localScale.z;
    InvokeRepeating("Spawn",0,Repeat);
}

void Spawn()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < spwn; i++)
    {
        float x = Random.Range(0, width);

        Debug.Log(x);
        float z = Random.Range(0, lenth);

        Debug.Log(z);
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, z);

        Instantiate(Enemy1, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Использую вот такой вот код, но спавнит он именно в координатах 0-40, никак не перед объектом.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6DaP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну наверное тебе нужно как раз отталкиваться от позиции объекта во всех координатах. То есть по `x` и `z` тоже. Примерно как-то так:

```
float x = Random.Range(-width / 2, width / 2);
float z = Random.Range(-lenth / 2, lenth / 2);
var pos =  transform.position;

var position = Vector3(pos.x + x, pos.y, pos.z + z);
Instantiate(Enemy1, pos, Quaternion.identity);
```

Длина, кстати, будет "len**g**th"

Comment: подправил void Spawn()
    {
        float q = Random.Range(1, 11);
        for (int i = 0; i < spwn; i++)
        {
            
            float x = Random.Range(-width / q, width / q);
            float z = Random.Range(-lenth / q, lenth / q);
            var pos = transform.position;

            var position = new Vector3(pos.x + x, pos.y, pos.z + z);
            Instantiate(Enemy1, position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        
    }